# converting eac3 to aac with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a number of video files stored on my Synology of which the audio doesn't play on when opening them with DS File. This is because DS File does not support eac3. I would like to convert those files to aac using ffmpeg, but when doing so, all audio is lost.

This is the file info:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '<file>.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.4.2 + libmatroska v1.6.4
  Duration: 00:48:43.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6566 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: eac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1 (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : English [SDH]
    Stream #0:3(ara): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      title           : Arabic
    Stream #0:4(chi): Subtitle: subrip
```

This is my attempt:

```
ffmpeg -i <file>.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c copy -c:a aac -b:a 640k output.mkv
```

Subtitles are kept, but audio is completely removed. I would like to automate the process if possible.

This is my ffmpeg configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.5.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --incdir='${prefix}/include/ffmpeg' --arch=i686 --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- --enable-cross-compile --enable-optimizations --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-version3 --enable-encoders --enable-pthreads --disable-protocols --disable-protocol=rtp --enable-protocol=file --enable-protocol=pipe --disable-muxer=image2 --disable-muxer=image2pipe --disable-swscale-alpha --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-bzlib --disable-altivec --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --disable-vaapi --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-decoder=aac --disable-decoder=aac_fixed --disable-encoder=aac --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=zmbv --disable-encoder=dca --disable-decoder=dca --disable-encoder=ac3 --disable-encoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=eac3 --disable-encoder=truehd --disable-decoder=truehd --disable-encoder=hevc_vaapi --disable-decoder=hevc --disable-muxer=hevc --disable-demuxer=hevc --disable-parser=hevc --disable-bsf=hevc_mp4toannexb --x86asmexe=yasm --cc=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-wrap-gcc --enable-yasm --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Synology does not support eac3 out of the box. So is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was apparently using the built-in ffmpeg, while I should be using the community package: https://synocommunity.com/packages

```
/path/to/ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -map 0 -c:s copy -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -b:a 640k "output.mkv"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding channels for audio as well along side bit rate to the command line after aac.

for 5.1 audio add:

```
-ac 6 -b:a 384k
```

For stereo audio add:

```
-ac 2 -b:a 128k
```

The final command would be like

```
ffmpeg -i <file>.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c copy -c:a aac -ac 6 -b:a 640k output.mkv
```

Comment: Same result. I have added my ffmpeg configuration to the original post.

Comment: try this `ffmpeg -i <file>.mkv -map 0:0 -c copy -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 640k -map 0:s? -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: Same result. Audio seems to be removed from the file. Subtitles remain though.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with your input file or the version of ffmpeg